# How can I delete a selection of data before the first required row

Tags: sql

OK my header might make this sound very simple indeed but the scenario I have is this:

I needed to get all practices for each week of the year with a cost of 0, then an update onto the table variable where these practices are inserted to. See a snippet of code and example below:

This is the main insert for the data

```
    insert into @Weeks
    select [practice id], name, description, fiscalweek, 0 as cost from dbo.Main
    cross join dbo.Time
    where Main.[Practice id] IN (110,109,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    AND Main.[TreatmentSchemeDescription] IN ('Access+','Access +')
    group by [practice id], name, description, fiscalweek
    order by [practice id]
```

Which produces data something like this

```
         practice id    fiscalweek          cost
               109             16           0.00
               109             17           0.00
               109             18           258.00
               109             19           0.00
               109             20           0.00
               109             21           80.00
               109             22           0.00
               109             23           0.00
               109             24           0.00
               109             25           0.00
               109             26           0.00
               109             27           0.00
               109             28           0.00
               109             29           0.00
               109             30           0.00
               109             31           0.00
```

Now the fiscalweek count runs from 1 - 54 I just couldn't justify putting them all here and there are a number of practices with entries for varying weeks not just those here, so for example practice 110 might have costs in the weeks 3, 7, 12 and 17 etc. What I need to do is delete from this table variable or temp table which ever works I don't mind, the zero cost entries before the first actual value entry in the list.

So for example if practice 110 has its first non-zero cost at week 2 then delete the row for week 1, but if practice 109 has its first actual non-zero cost in week 18 then delete all zero entries prior to week 18. But I don't want to delete the zero cost rows between the weeks that have a cost. Basically this is so I can run an average of the cost over the weeks that a practice has costs from the first non-zero cost they have.

This would be straightforward if all practices had costs in the same weeks, and if I didn't care about the zero costs in between, but I need to keep those that are in between.

I thought this would be simple but my mind has gone trying to work this out.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply not put them there in the first place.  Do something like this:

```
select * 
from 
(your existing query goes here) temp
where cost > 0
```

Also, the order by clause in an insert query is probably not necessary.

Comment: I have used a cross join to create a list of 0 costs against every practice so that I can update those that I want with the corresponding figure. This is the only way I can get all the fiscal weeks otherwise any other join (Left, Right, Full etc.) will only return the actual fiscal weeks where there is a cost.

I don't need the order by in the insert you're correct there. By selecting all where the cost > 0 will return exactly that and I will lose the zero entries between the weeks that have actual figures.